# dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, openvz, debian-wheezy

On interactive login I get:

```
dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given
```

But I *do* have SHELL variable set:

```
% set | grep SHELL
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
```

In `~/.bash_profile` I source `.dircolors` like that:

```
eval "`dircolors ~/.dircolors`"
```

I have done this on other Linux hosts and it was never a problem, but when I do `vzctl enter $CTID` (OpenVZ container with Debian wheezy), this always appears.

Why is it doing that? And how do I fix that?

Comment: Have you solved ?

Comment: Same problem here. SHELL variable is set. Works in all environments but my Visual Studio Code with GitBash (but even there SHELL variable is set).

Answer (score 2):

Try to check the environment variables using `env` command and see if the `SHELL` variable exist.

`set` can also see shell-local variables, which only accessible by the current shell, not by every executed program [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5657113/7168030)]

If `SHELL` variable doesn't exist you can export it using `export SHELL`

Comment: What should the `SHELL` variable be?

Comment: @Turkeyphant Something like `/bin/bash`